# Verificar al Hacer Un UPDATE Y No Dejar Crear Un Nuevo Registro PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo El Siguiente codigo el cual hace un chequeo lo que no logro hacer es que cuando un usuario vuelva a checar no lo deje si es que un registro ya Esta en un BD, espero y alguien pueda ayudarme

```html
<?php

include "../Funciones/Conexion.php";
$mysqli = inicio();


$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');  
$horaS = date('g:i:s');


$sql = "UPDATE chequeo 
SET horaS = '$horaS' 
WHERE fecha = '$fecha'";

$verificar_fecha = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM chequeo WHERE horaS = '$horaS'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar_fecha) > 0 ){
 echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Error",text:"Ya Checaste tu Dia De Salida, No Puedes Volver a Checar",type:"error",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="../Usuario.php";});});</script>';
 exit;
}


$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if ($query){
echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Exito",text:"Has Checado Con Exito",type:"success",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="../Usuario.php";});});</script>';
}else{
echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Error",text:"Ocurrrio Un Error Al Checar",type:"error",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="../Usuario.php";});});</script>';
}
?>
```

PSD: ya cambie $horaS = date('g:i:s'); por $horaS = time('g:i:s'); ya Que me habian dicho que funciona asi pero no lo hace

Comment: primero `"SELECT * FROM chequeo WHERE horaS = '$horaS'" `estas comparando con `horas`, creo que tu problema va un poco mas de logica, en base de datos se guarda hora minutos   y segundos, verifica el campo en db si no esta algo asi yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00, si es asi solo debes agregarle el 00:00:00 o puedes hacer el where algo asi `where DATE_FORMAT(fecha ,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$fecha'"`

Comment: ya Lo he Echo y pues todo esta bien, simplemente no lo hace

Comment: el error es que no estas ejecutando la consulta de guardado `mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql); `esta linea va antes del select

Comment: Buen Comentario @JackNavaRow Pero Aun Hace El UPDATE, Ya Verifica Pero Sigue Haciendo El UPDATE

Comment: trata de imprimir el query que tiene la variable $verificar_hora e intenta ejecutarlo en phpmyadmin

Comment: El funcionamiento de tu código depende de varios factores. 1º que la conexión a la bd sea correcta, 2º que la consulta se ejecute correctamente, 3º que ésta devuelva datos y para que devuelva datos deben cumplirse los criterios del WHERE... verificando que el campo fecha que estás pasando y los datos que existen en la bd tienen el formato adecuado (se suele fallar mucho con los datos de fecha). ¿Verificaste eso? Además tu código está implementado en base a 2 malas prácticas de programación: la 1ª es no usar consultas preparadas y la 2ª es usar código JS embebido directamente en el archivo.

Comment: Puedes poner la estructura de tu tabla e intentar explicar un poco más tu problema.  No terminó de estar seguro de de que es lo que tienes y que es lo que buscas.